# Find Specified Color In Each Frame Of Real-time Video

Tags: matlab, real-time, rgb, detection

I am newbie in Matlab.

My Boss gave me a task and i stuck in last step.

the task is:
user should specify a rectangle in snapshot of real-time video and then i should detect the mean color of that rectangle in each frame of video.

first user specify the boundaries of rectangle in a snapshot of video with this code:

```
    test = getsnapshot(vid);
    imwrite(test,'mytest.png','png');
    testsnap = imread('mytest.png');
    Rectpos=getrect;
```

then I calculate mean degree of each `R , G , B` :

```
    bbx=boundingboxPixels(testsnap,Rectpos(1),Rectpos(2),Rectpos(3),Rectpos(4));
    rRect=mean(bbx(:,:,1));
    gRect=mean(bbx(:,:,2));
    bRect=mean(bbx(:,:,3));
```

where `boundingboxPixels` method is like this :

```
function pixel_vals = boundingboxPixels(img, x_init, y_init, x_width, y_width)

    if x_init > size(img,2)
        error('x_init lies outside the bounds of the image.'); end
    if y_init > size(img,1)
        error('y_init lies outside the bounds of the image.'); end

    if y_init+y_width > size(img,1) || x_init+x_width > size(img,2) || ...
            x_init < 1 || y_init < 1
        warning([...
            'Given rectangle partially falls outside image. ',...
            'Resizing rectangle...']);
    end

    x_min   = max(1, uint16(x_init));
    y_min   = max(1, uint16(y_init));
    x_max   = min(size(img,2), x_min+uint16(x_width));
    y_max   = min(size(img,1), y_min+uint16(y_width));
    x_range = x_min : x_max;
    y_range = y_min : y_max;

    Upper = img( x_range, y_min  , :);
    Left  = img(   x_min, y_range, :);
    Right = img(   x_max, y_range, :);
    Lower = img( x_range, y_max  , :);

    pixel_vals = [...
        Upper
        permute(Left, [2 1 3])
        permute(Right, [2 1 3])
        Lower];

end
```

then get the calculated Mean of `RGB` color with a threshold from each frame of video:

```
tv=getdata(vid,1);//vid is real-time video            
r=tv(:,:,1,1);
g=tv(:,:,2,1);
b=tv(:,:,3,1);

redVal = (r >= rRect-thr) & (r <= rRect+thr);
greenVal = (g >= gRect-thr) & (g <= gRect+thr);
blueVal = (b >= bRect-thr) & (b <= bRect+thr);
```

Now How Should I use the `redVal , greenVal , blueVal` to detect this color?

Comment: Just AND them (&) and you get a logical matrix where the ones describe the positions where the thresholded color is.

Comment: @Steffen thanks but how do i convert the matrix positions to matrix of color values?

Comment: I think redVal describe where a red component is detected, same for green and blue. By and-ing you will find positions where all three components are in range. Since you specified which color you want to detect, why would you want to use the detected positions to get the color on which basis it was detected?

Comment: Create a mask which gives you the 2D positions which are in color range (as suggested by Steffen): `mask = redVal & greenVal & blueVal;`. Now you should be able to create whatever you want, e.g. `everythingBlackButColorWhichIsInRange = cat(3,r.*mask,g.*mask,b.*mask)` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

as Steffen said , problem  solved by adding `&` between arrays